# var vs := in Go

Tags: go, variable-assignment, colon-equals

In the Go web server example here: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#web_server

The following line of code works

```
var addr = flag.String("addr", ":1718", "http service address")
```

but changing it to

```
addr := flag.String("addr", ":1718", "http service address")
```

is a compilation error. Why? Does it have anything to do with the face that the return type of the function is `*string` instead of `string`? What difference does that make?

**UPDATE**: Thanks for pointing out that `:=` is not allowed at the top level. Any idea why this inconsistency is in the spec? I don't see any reason for the behaviour to be different inside a block.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On the updated question: there is actually a difference between long and short declarations, being in that short form allows redeclaration of variables.

From [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.
>
> ```
> field1, offset := nextField(str, 0)
> field2, offset := nextField(str, offset)  // redeclares offset
> a, a := 1, 2                              // illegal: double declaration of a or no new variable if a was declared elsewhere
> ```

So I'd say the `:=` operator is not pure *declare*, but more like *declare and assign*.
Redeclaration in toplevel is not allowed, so neither are short declarations.

Another reason for this might be syntax simplicity. In Go all toplevel forms start with either `type`, `var` or `func`. Short declarations there will ruin all the cuteness.

Comment: it was actually just syntactic sugar for declaration+assignment in previous go versions.

Answer (score 45):

In Go, top-level variable assignments *must* be prefixed with the `var` keyword. Omitting the `var` keyword is only allowed within blocks.

```
package main

var toplevel = "Hello world"         // var keyword is required

func F() {
        withinBlock := "Hello world" // var keyword is not required
}
```

Answer (score 11):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)
>
> A short variable declaration uses the syntax:
>
> ```
> ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .
> ```
>
> Short variable declarations may appear only inside functions.

In your example, changing the variable declaration statement outside a function body

```
var addr = flag.String("addr", ":1718", "http service address")
```

to a short variable declaration statement outside a function body

```
addr := flag.String("addr", ":1718", "http service address")
```

fails with compiler error "non-declaration statement outside function body."